# Why does'nt the logo link go anywhere?

Tags: html

http://www.nanaplum.com/collections/frontpage/products/hurricane-sandy-red-cross

The logo is a link, and its href is http://www.nanaplum.com

but it does not actually work, why?

Comment: Your div with id `cart-summary` seems to be affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the css attribute `position:relative` in `div#cart-summary`.

This makes `div#cart-summary` overloop the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the padding top and height of this #cart-summary.This div moves over that logo so that the link not working.

Answer (score 0):

div#cart-summary is in front of it.

Tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome's [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) are nice for debugging this kind of problem. In Chrome, you can right-click >> Inspect Element and then poke around. When you do this you can manipulate the page, try something like deleting that div node, find the link becomes accessible, then decide how to fix it in your markup or CSS.

Now go learn about [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index).